# What are the security challenges encountered with attribute exchange?

Tags: privacy, openid, oauth

OpenID has [Attribute Exchange](http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html), Facebook has [Facebook Connect](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2008/05/09/announcing-facebook-connect/), and authorization services such as [Oauth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) enable access to user data distributed across a range of content providers.

***What are the security challenges that these services face?***

Comment: This sounds like a homework essay rather than a question for a Q&A forum like this one. You think you could winnow this down a bit to something more specific?

Comment: You're right, thanks for the comment. I've reduced the scope of this one and added a new one here, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20746/what-attribute-exchange-services-are-available.

Comment: It still feels a little too broad to me. StackExchange as a whole has a preference for strictly answerable questions, whereas this seems like any number of questions could be correct.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. I noticed there wasn't much discussion of attribute exchange on here so I wanted to kick things off :-)

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day the client (usually a browser) still needs a token to maintain a session (usually with a cookie variable).   If the attacker gets this token,  by XSS or [OWASP A9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection) then they can access the same resources.  CSRF is also a concern.

Now this is assuming that these authentication providers are totally immune from attack.  If a flaw exists in one of these services,  you are also in trouble.   SQL Injection,  Phishing, Insecure backups,  lack of brute force protection are just a few concerns.

[oauzz](http://code.google.com/p/oauzz/) is an oauth fuzzer,  which can uncover serious flaws in an oauth implementation.